# Meteor how to upload image via rest api to aws s3?

Tags: api, meteor, postman

I am working on api to upload images on aws s3. First i need to save images to aws and then need to save url to mongo database.But when i am trying to upload image getting this error. I am using lepozepo:s3 library on clinet side and want to use same at server side. Code that i had mentioned below is with lepozepo library.  http://prntscr.com/ohareb

```
 Meteor.call('uploadProfilePic', this.request.body, function (error, resp) {

    if (error) {
       response = {
          "errorCode": true,
         "statusMessage": error.message,
        } 

    }else{
        response = {
        "errorCode": false,
        "statusMessage": "Picture uploaded successfully",
      }
    }

});

this.response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.response.end(JSON.stringify(response));
```

});

and in methods i have created this method.

```
 uploadProfilePic:function(image){
  var files = image;
  userId = "MMKKK79KQ7eMs6777Hh";
  import {S3} from "meteor/lepozepo:s3";

  console.log(files);

  S3.uploadFile({ 
    files:files,
    path:"avatars"
  },function(e,r){
    if (!e) {
      var $set={};
      $set[templ.data.picType]=r.secure_url;
      Meteor.users.update({
        _id: userId
      }, {
        $set: $set
      }, function(err) {
        if (!err) {
          console.log( "Image uploaded");
        } else {
          console.log("Error updating image");
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log( "Error updating image");
    }
});

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload files to Amazon S3 with Meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19570496/how-to-upload-files-to-amazon-s3-with-meteor)

Answer (score 1):

I maintain this package: https://github.com/activitree/s3up-meta.
With it you can upload and delete files to/from S3. You can also set metadata for cacheing and expire which you can anyway overwrite from your Cloudfront CDN (in case you distribute your images via Cloudfront).
The package is based on the AWS sdk and all requests are signed by the Meteor server, however, files are moved from client straight to S3.
Open a question on the Git if you need.
Cheers